# Android Firestore get field values by document id

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore database in which I have to get all the field's inside a document by document id.
[image: Firestore Database]

How to get the all the field values (inside Green Box) by document id (Red box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get that specific document you can try this

```
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("projects").document("YOURDOCIDHERE");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

If you want get all documents by key order then you can try making a query like this.

```
docRef.orderByKey()
```

Check firebase documention for more info.